# Галерея fancybox в слайдах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

Необходимо реализовать слайдер (swiper), в котором при нажатии на слайд появляется модальное окно fancybox c галереей изображений (на каждом слайде своя галерея). Код почти готов, не могу сообразить на что необходимо повесить fancybox.

```js
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    freeMode: true, 
  });

  $("#slide-1").click(function() {
    $("gallery-1").fancybox([
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
    ]);
  });

  $("#gallery-2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
    ]);
  });

  $("#gallery-3").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
    ]);
  });

  $("#gallery-4").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
      'https://picsum.photos/300/200/',
    ]);
  });
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #eee;
  display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.items {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.items:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.description-items {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.6/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div id="slide-1" class="swiper-slide">
      <a id="gallery-1"><div class="items" style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/300/200/) no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></div></a>
      <div class="description-items">Слайды 1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2" class="swiper-slide">
      <a id="gallery-2"><div class="items" style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/300/200/) no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></div></a>
      <div class="description-items">Слайды 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3" class="swiper-slide">
      <a id="gallery-3"><div class="items" style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/300/200/) no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></div></a>
      <div class="description-items">Слайды 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4" class="swiper-slide">
      <a id="gallery-4"><div class="items" style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/300/200/) no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></div></a>
      <div class="description-items">Слайды 4</div>
    </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем правильно отображает, поэтому вот ссылка на jsfiddle. [Код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AShukilovich/3pnhvx10/)